# Performing matrix operations on a very large[25000 x 25000] in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, matrix, out-of-memory

I have a project in which i have to perform matrix computation on a dense matrix , but I am getting outOfMemory error, when doing so, Can you suggest me other way of doing it. I am normally doing it using

```
double [][] a= new double[25000][25000];

for(int i=0;i<25000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<25000;j++){

    a[i][j];
    //some computation like adding multiplication etc...
    }
}
```

in java.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : java

Comment: those loops will have nothing to do with the out of memory

Comment: I guess it due to the huge array that i am allocating.

Comment: how much memory do you have?

Comment: I have 4 GB ram, heap space is 512

Comment: @Vitamon: it is dense

Comment: FYI: The array is about 2.3 GB. Edit: Okay it's a double now. Then 4.6 GB.

Comment: I know, I am looking for an alternative to do this computation, can you suggest something which is time efficient as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using Dynamic array, where I created 1 row and 1 column then performed multiplication and saved results new array.

```
double sum=0;

                //Multiply matrix and adding to sum
                for(int j:cit){
                    sum+=(rowCitation[j]*rOld[j]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need about 5GB to declare this matrix:

```
25000*25000*8 bytes = 5000000000 bytes => 4.7GB
```

If you have this avaible RAM, you can run your application using this JVM options:

```
java  -Xms64m -Xmx5120m [other options...]
```

This way you tell to JVM that it can take until 5GB of RAM.

Comment: I have just 4GB available though :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the RAM for it, you'll have to store the matrix in a file and seek to the data you need as necessary.

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("matrix")));
for(int i=0;i<25000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<25000;j++){
        double value = //Compute value
        out.writeDouble(value);
    }
}
out.close();
```

Then to get the value at position (i, j)

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("matrix");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);

fis.getChannel().position((i * 25000L + j) * (Double.SIZE / 8));
double value = in.readDouble();
```

Note that file reads are already really slow, but seeking to a particular position is even slower.  If you can figure out how to order your reads and writes so you don't have to seek every time, you'll be in much better shape.  Also, you may want to put each column or row in a separate file depending on how you intend to use the matrix.  You may also want to look at using Octave or Matlab instead of Java.